# how come I cannot do a Math.max on an array that has been sliced out of the another array

Tags: javascript, arrays, max

I am looking for a max number in each subarrays of an array. But when I did that it give me NaN. Why?

Let me outline what I've found. For context, I perform these tests in the console of Google Chrome.

Original array:

```
let arr = [[4, 5, 1, 3], [13, 27, 18, 26]];
```

I slice out the 1st subarray and assigned to arr1.

```
let arr1 = arr.slice(0, 1);
arr1;
 [4, 5, 1, 3]
arr1[0];   //this is to see if I can get value at index 0
 [4, 5, 1, 3]
arr1.length;
1
```

When I perform the Math.max on arr1, I get NaN.

```
Math.max(...arr1);
NaN
```

When I couldn't get the Math.max value, I thought arr1 wasn't an array so I test to see if it is an array:

```
Array.isArray(arr1)
true
```

I was able to get the max number from the subarray using the original arry. My question is why I cannot get the Math.max on arr1, the array that sliced out of the original?

Answer (score 4):

`arr1` is an array of arrays, not an array of numbers. You can flatten the array before using `Math.max`. (Note: if you just want the `i`th subarray, just use `arr[i]` instead of `slice`. `slice` is only useful when you want multiple consecutive elements from an array.)

```js
let arr = [[4, 5, 1, 3], [13, 27, 18, 26]];
let arr1 = arr.slice(0, 1);
console.log(JSON.stringify(arr1));
let max = Math.max(...arr1.flat());
console.log(max);
```

Comment: Or just `arr[0]`. No need to create an array just to toss it via `flat`... :-)

Answer (score 0):

Your `arr1` **isn't** `[4, 5, 1, 3]`, it's `[[4, 5, 1, 3]]` — an array containing a single element, which is an array of numbers. `slice` creates an array containing the elements you've selected from the original array (just the first one in your case). That first element in `arr` is an array, so you end up with an array containing that array.

If you want to use `arr1` as you've shown, just use `arr[0]`, not `arr.slice(0, 1)`:

```js
let arr = [[4, 5, 1, 3], [13, 27, 18, 26]];
let arr1 = arr[0];
console.log(Math.max(...arr1));
```

Comment: Appreciate your response. I ended up not using the arr1 because it made my head hurts.